# How can a circle be written as $|z-z_0| = r$ or as $z\bar{z} - z\bar{z_0} - \bar{z}z_0 + |z_0|^2 = r^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Show that the equation to a circle with center at $z_0$ and radius $r$ can be written as $$|z-z_0| = r$$ or as $$z\bar{z} - z\bar{z_0} - \bar{z}z_0 + |z_0|^2 = r^2$$

I let $z_0 = (x_0 + iy_0) = (x_0,y_0)$. Now I have $$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2$$

I know $x=\frac{1}{2}(z+\bar{z})$ and $y = \frac{1}{2i}(z-\bar{z})$.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I seem to be having issues with these types of geometric characterization problems.

Comment: Full answer: $$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=|(x-x_0)+i(y-y_0)|^2=|(x+iy)-(x_0+iy_0)|^2=|z-z_0|^2$$

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{C}$, we should think about $|z|$ as $|z-0|$ which means distance of $z$ from origin. Similarly, we should understand $|a-b|$ as *distance* between $a$ and $b$.

Then *what is circle*?

This is actually not a precise question. The precise question would be *what is circle around $z_0$ of radius $r$?* You know, it is set of points $z$ whose distance from $z_0$ is $r$, and  what your equation says now?

Answer (score 0):

Since cirlce is a collection of points equidistant from a fixed point, let $z_0$, so distance which is $|z-z_0|=r$.As $|x|^2=x\bar x$, we have:
$$|z-z_0|^2=r^2\implies (z-z_0)(\bar z-\bar z_0)=r^2\implies...$$